# Kafka implementation with ELK

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, filebeat, elk

I'm currently using:

- filebeat 8.1.3 (installed on Windows),
- Elasticsearch version 7.17.1
- logstash 8.1.3
- kafka
  elk, kafka are on 1 server

About architecture, I firstly installed filebeat on Windows to get logs from there. then I want to use it to output log to kafka, and from kafka to logstash. Finally from logstash to elasticsearch.
Just like the image below

[![Screenshot_3](upload://mrfJpBEI44Y1XDAhlrsrBVHX6Oh)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEbhI.png)

However, I'm having problem with not seeing logs from kafka/logstash (from Windows filebeat) on Kibana.
My filebeat config (filebeat.yml) on Windows:

> - type: log
>   paths:
>
>   - "E:/QwikCilver/Applogs/AppLog/zeus/zeus.log"
>     ignore_older: 5m
>     scan_frequency: 1m
>     close_inactive: 10s
>     close_removed: true
>     clean_removed: true
>     close_renamed: true
>     multiline.type: pattern
>     multiline.pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
>     multiline.negate: true
>     multiline.match: after
>     tags: ["Perf", "zeus.log" ]
>
> output.kafka:
> hosts: ["internal-a6a50c1cf23db4fa582d77b7a28d2fc9-485248067.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com:9092"]
> enabled: true
> topic: "my_topic"
> partition.round_robin:
> reachable_only: false
>
> required_acks: 1
> compression: gzip
> max_message_bytes: 1000000

My logstash config:

> ```
> input {
>   kafka {
>     bootstrap_servers => "kafka-broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092"
>     topics => ["my_topic"]
>     codec => json
>   }
> }
> filter {
>  }
> output {
>   elasticsearch {
>         index => "others-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
>         hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
>         user => elastic
>         password => *********
>         }
> }
> ```

I don't know what should I do, is there maybe something wrong with topics setup on Windows? or what I should do to get logs from filebeat on Windows to Elasticsearch through kafka and logstash?

I am new to this kafka set up.
Kafka has been set up using
https://github.com/meniem/kafka-helm/tree/main

Tried to go inside the kafka cli container and able to create and send topic and get the data on kibana.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use Elasticsearch 8.x with Filebeat / Logstash of the same version.

Second, Kafka nor Logstash are necessary as Filebeat can directly output to Elasticsearch.

Or [Filebeat can send TCP events](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html) to Logstash, also without Kafka.

> Kafka has been set up using...

1. That repo isn't maintained.
2. You've pointed Filebeat at some AWS server, which doesn't match your Logstash bootstrap-servers

Alternatively, Kafka Connect can read files and write to Elasticsearch as well, so you don't need Filebeat or Logstash, if you did want to use Kafka.

Comment: we already have a working set up for Filebeat and ELK. We are just trying to add kafka in between filebeat and logstash since we have a high flow of logs and want to add a queue mechanism.

Comment: Okay, well, it's not clear where each of those components is running. If you want to run Kafka in k8s, then use Strimzi, not an unmaintained Helm chart. https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/17/accessing-kafka-part-1/